# Google Sign-In gapi.auth2 Error

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-signin

Google login implemented in my website by following 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthissignedinlistenwzxhzdk44listenerwzxhzdk45

My website link
https://golearn.social27.com/academy/login

But i am getting Error on IE 11

gapi.auth2.ExternallyVisibleError: gapi.auth2 has been initialized with different options. Consider calling gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() instead of gapi.auth2.init()

What is wrong here?
My code is here:

```
<div class="g-signin2" onclick="checkAuth();" style="display:none">

function checkAuth() {
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks the authentication, click event of the google auth.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        gapi.auth2.init({ client_id: clientId });
        var googleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        googleAuth.currentUser.listen(onSignInCallback);
        googleAuth.signIn(
            {
                'scope': 'profile email'
            }
        );
    }
    /**
     * Handler for the signin callback triggered after the user selects an account.
     */
    function onSignInCallback(resp) {
        var googleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        var user = googleAuth.currentUser.get();

        MethodToDO(user.getBasicProfile().getGivenName(), user.getBasicProfile().getFamilyName(), user.getBasicProfile().getEmail(), user.getBasicProfile().getEmail());//user.getBasicProfile().getId()
    }
```